# can anyone please explain why vb 2008 MDI application child forms moving after another child form is opend/closed

Tags: vb.net

Hope I can explain this. MDI parent opens with a menu strip. Click on lets say customers and customer child form opens in spot I want it to. I have startup centered to parent and maximized. If I then click on Vendors the vendor form opens up in correct spot. But when I click to close the Vendor child form the customer form is no longer in same spot. Still maximized but all controls have moved lower. Anybody know how to keep the forms in same position inside MDI.

Answer (score 0):

I find that behavior odd. Usually the new MDI child will open up in a different spot but the other forms should stay static. You could have the parent specifically set the position of the children (and re-set them on child forms closing, etc.). You should be able to specify the location with the Location property. Put a method on the parent to reposition it's children to the default locations and then you can call it from the children (on their close event).

Comment: I can't figure this out. I open 2 child forms. When I close one of them the other has shifted. Anybody know how to stop this.